# The use of checked exception for errors to be dealt with in web layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, exception

I am having a hard time organizing how I should deal with errors that occur in the service layer. The reason for throwing that exception in this method is when the password provided is to weak or the confirmation id is wrong. The name of the exception is not settled yet though.

However, are checked exceptions to be avoided in a new application anyway? If so, how do I communicate errors like this to the caller? The caller in this scenario is the web layer which exposes a web service. I want to handle the error in the web layer and create a error message.

I have a method:

```
boolean confirmPasswordReset(int accountId, String confirmationId, String newPassword) throws ConstraintViolation;
```

And this is the exception class:

```
public class ConstraintViolation extends Exception {

    public ConstraintViolation(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

From reading this article it looks like it should be right:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html

> Contingency
>
> - Is considered to be: A part of the design
> - Is expected to happen: Regularly but rarely
> - Who cares about it: The upstream code that invokes the method Examples: Alternative return modes
> - Best Mapping: A checked exception

Answer (score 0):

I try to use checked exceptions as little as possible. I think using a runtime exception and documenting it clearly is enough.

From your case, you seem to be the one designing and controlling the web layer. In that case, you already know what runtime exceptions your service layer throws and how to handle them. You don't need to be told by the compiler.

I would only use a checked exception if the exception is recoverable, and the client of the code is external where I have to force it to handle the exception. Even then, the result will most likely be one more empty catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a good discussion of the pro's and con's of both approaches. 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/checked-or-unchecked-exceptions.html

What I think is important (similiar to the author of article above) is that you choose which way to go (checked or unchecked)  and then stay consistent. Otherwise you'll end up with a messy codebase and will likely suffer from the downsides of both approaches.